# Access-Control-Allow-Origin code 405?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, jhipster, satellizer

I am developing a mobile application using Jhipster and Jhipster-ionic along with cordova.
Currently, I am using Token-based AngularJS Authentication ([Satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer)) to Login with OAuth 2.0 and I have an issue with CROSS origin.

I followed this example on  [Satellizer-ionic](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/tree/master/examples/ionic) and I did the fallowing

My Config:

```
 .config(function($authProvider) {
   $authProvider.httpInterceptor = false;
   $authProvider.withCredentials = true;

    var commonConfig = {
      popupOptions: {
        location: 'yes',
        toolbar: 'yes',
        width: window.screen.width,
        height: window.screen.height
      }
    };

    if (ionic.Platform.isIOS() || ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
      commonConfig.redirectUri = 'http://localhost:3000/';
    }

    $authProvider.facebook(angular.extend({}, commonConfig, {
      clientId: 'MyFacebookId',
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/social/signup'
    }));

    $authProvider.google(angular.extend({}, commonConfig, {
      clientId: 'Myid.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/social/signup'


      }));
      })
      .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
          if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
          }
          if (window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
          }
        });
      });
```

Controller :

```
vm.authenticate = function(provider) {
  $auth.authenticate(provider)
    .then(function(res) {
      $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'Success',
        content: 'You have successfully logged in!'
      })
      console.log("yes google login works");
      console.log('success', 'Welcome', 'Thanks for coming back, ' + res.user.displayName + '!');

    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
      $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'Error',
        content: error.message || (error.data && error.data.message) || error
      });
      console.log("too bad" + error.data);
    });
};
```

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-full btn-fb active db" ng-click="vm.authenticate('google')" type="submit" translate="{{'welcome.loginGoogle' |translate}}"></button>

<button class="btn btn-full btn-fb active db" ng-click="vm.authenticate('facebook')" type="submit" translate="{{'welcome.loginFacebook' |translate}}"></button>
```

But I got this error:

[image]

I have uncomment the cors on application.yml

```
cors: #By default CORS are not enabled. Uncomment to enable.
        allowed-origins: "*"
        allowed-methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
        allowed-headers: "*"
        exposed-headers:
        allow-credentials: true
        max-age: 1800
```

My Jhipster version is v3.5.1.

Comment: Have you tried doing what the error says? You need to have an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header present with your authorized domain.

Comment: @MattClark Yes, i tried but it does not work.

Comment: This is a back end CORS problem...all your front end code is meaningless

Comment: I am using jhipster, the cross is already configured

Comment: have you tried to run it in device ?

Comment: @Agapitz, yes, I did but it does not work !

Comment: try to install Allow-Control-Allow-Origin plugin in your google chrome and turn it on then run your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some Mistake on my code the commonConfig.redirectUri should be my backend URL, here the solution:

```
.config(function($authProvider) {
   $authProvider.httpInterceptor = false;
   $authProvider.withCredentials = true;

    var commonConfig = {
      popupOptions: {
        location: 'yes',
        toolbar: 'yes',
        width: window.screen.width,
        height: window.screen.height
      }
    };

    if (ionic.Platform.isIOS() || ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
    commonConfig.redirectUri = 'http://localhost:8080/sigin/google';
    }

    $authProvider.google(angular.extend({}, commonConfig, {
      clientId: 'googleAppId',
     // url: "http://localhost:8080/sigin/google"
    }));
    console.log($authProvider);
  })
  .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    console.log($ionicPlatform);
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      }
      if (window.StatusBar) {
        StatusBar.styleDefault();
      }
    });
  });
```